# Find length of the longest column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Currently I have the following dataframe:

```
data = {'shoe': ['a', 'b'], 'fury': ['c','d','e','f'], 'chaos': ['g','h', 'i']}
dataFrame = pandas.DataFrame({k:pandas.Series(v) for k, v in data.items()})
```

Output:

```
  shoe fury chaos
0    a    c     g
1    b    d     h
2  NaN    e     i
3  NaN    f   NaN
```

Is there a way to find the length of the longest column in a dataframe? In this case this should be 4. Does `pandas` have a method available for similar purposes?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using `count` followed by `max`. According to [pandas documentation for the count](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html):

> Count non-NA cells for each column or row.

```
print(dataFrame.count().max())
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you create the dataframe via `dict` , which means the longest columns is equal to the length of df,so

```
len(df)
Out[368]: 4
```

Comment: This would not work if you have `'fury': ['c','d','e','f',np.nan]` for example as your longest Series

Answer (score 2):

@student's and @Wen's answers are the best but a python solution would be:

```
print(len(max(dataFrame,key=lambda x: dataFrame[x].count())))
```

I definitely wouldn't recommend this, because it's inefficient, this is the last option i will choose :-), at least it works :-)

Answer (score 1):

#### You can apply a lambda to your vectors:

```
df.apply(lambda x: len(x.dropna()))

chaos    3
fury     4
shoe     2
dtype: int64

df.apply(lambda x: len(x.dropna())).max()
4
```

Comment: @ W.Dodge, i love the answer , as it also clearly demonstrates each column length in case one have to see or present it , my +1.

Answer (score 0):

@student's answer is better, but as an alternative:

```
>>> dataFrame.notnull().sum(0).max()
4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the last valid index:

```
LVI = df.last_valid_index()         # 3
```

To get the *length* of the longest column, you can use `pd.Index.get_loc`:

```
length = df.index.get_loc(LVI) + 1  # 4
```

If your index is the default `pd.IndexRange`, then you can simply use `LVI + 1`.